# How to display part of an image using a for loop from a picturebox array

Tags: arrays, graphics, vb.net-2010, picturebox

There may be a simple answer but i have tried quite a few things and nothing seems to work unless i just manually display the images but what i want is to use this sub for other pictures as well which i will fix later once i get it to display these images. My code is as follows

```
Private Sub updateStandardToolbar()
    'Draws the sprites to the pictureboxes
    Dim bit As New Bitmap(gridSize, gridSize)
    Dim dest_rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, gridSize, gridSize)
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    ' Associate a Graphics object with the Bitmap
    Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bit)

    For y As Integer = 0 To standardNum.Y
        For x As Integer = 0 To standardNum.X
            Call getSrcRect(x, y)

            'Copy that part of the image.
            gr.DrawImage(bmpStandardTile, dest_rect, src_rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

            'Display the result.
            pb(i).Image = bit

            i += 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem with this code is all the pictureboxes (pb()) displays the same picture which is the last one on my image. StandardNum.x and standardNum.y are variables which hold 3 and 1 respectively. bmpStandardTile is the image I want to copy from and hopefully dest_rect and src_rect is self explanatory =). Any helps is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. I just found the answer to my own problem after looking at why the pictureboxes displays the same image. Here is my code and how i fixed it if anyone else has a similar or the same problem.

```
Private Sub updateStandardToolbar()
    'Draws the sprites to the pictureboxes
    Dim bit As Bitmap
    Dim dest_rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, gridSize, gridSize)
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    ' Associate a Graphics object with the Bitmap
    'Dim gr As Graphics

    'For u As Integer = 0 To maxPics
    '    bit = New Bitmap(gridSize, gridSize)
    'Next

    For y As Integer = 0 To standardNum.Y
        For x As Integer = 0 To standardNum.X
            bit = New Bitmap(gridSize, gridSize)
            Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bit)
            Call getSrcRect(x, y)

            'Copy that part of the image.
            gr.DrawImage(bmpStandardTile, dest_rect, src_rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

            'Display the result.
            pb(i).Image = bit

            i += 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The answer was actually very simple. Silly me. I forgot to clear the bitmap image so it will not change the image which the last picturebox was using.

```
bit = New Bitmap(gridSize, gridSize)
```

Anyway Learnt from my mistakes =)